# How to insert a dataframe into another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframe like below.
df1:

```
  col1 col2    col3    col4
0   45   69  string  string
```

df2:

```
   col5    col8
0    45      37
1  data  random
```

I want to combine these two into one dataframe.
resultant df:

```
col1 col2    col3    col4
  45   69  string  string
--------- 1 or 2 empty rows here -------------
col5    col8
   45      37
 data  random
```

I tried the append method but that puts `col5` and `col8` as columns. I want to combine df1 and df2. col1, col2 and other column names don't even have to be column names in the resultant dataframe. They can be values in a row. I am trying to create a summary in the resultant dataframe.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the docs? Pandas has `concat`, `join` and `merge` methods, have a look https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas.concat

Comment: A dataframe isn't ever going to be formatted like your desired output... they don't have randomly blank lines with new column names, that's just not how a dataframe works. Are you talking about *exporting* two dataframes in this format to a CSV or something?

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice such as "Any help is appreciated."  With that as a caveat, the use of a dataframe for your expected results doesn't make sense.  A DF is a collection of rows with  arranged as columns of simial information.  Leaving rows blank doesn't make sense in this context, nor does having a Column labeled Col1 with row data containing a col5 header.  While it is valid to have mixed data types in a column this makes processing a df much more difficult.

Comment: @alec_djinn, Hi. I checked those methods too. Couldn't make it work.

Comment: @BeRT2me, Yes. I want to export it as csv.

Comment: @FrankShrestha what have you tried? What is not working? Alos, please post a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# write first dataframe
df1.to_csv('file.csv')

# append empty line
with open('file.csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write('\n\n')

# append second dataframe
df2.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a')
```

Output:

```
,col1,col2,col3,col4
0,45,69,string,string

,col5,col8
0,45,37
1,data,random
```

Comment: This worked well except it didn't add an empty row. Thanks.
I added an empty row with `df1=df1.append(pd.DataFrame([[''] * len(df1.columns)], columns=df1.columns))`.